# error sorting array in c language

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, visual-studio-2013

Program to write number of goals scored by each player in a arranged list

Sorting array in C language code is showing error "did not evaluate to constant" in Visual Studio.

```
int main() {

    int i,temp,swaped; 
    int howmany = 10;
    int goal[howmany];

    for (i = 0;i <= howmany;i++) {
        goal[i] = (rand() % 40)+1;
    }
    printf("orignal list");
    for (i = 0;i <= howmany;i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goal[i]);
    }
    while (1) {
        swaped = 0;
        for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
            if (goal[i] > goal[i + 1]) {
                goal[i] = temp;
                goal[i] = goal[i + 1];
                goal[i + 1] = temp;
                swaped = 1;
            }

        }
        if (swapped == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("sorted list");
        for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
            printf("%d \n", goal[i]);
        }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that you're code won't work as it overruns the end of the array three times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 has a very old and creaky C compiler which, even after all these years, still does not yet understand C99. So you'll need to change this:

```
int howmany = 10;
int goal[howmany];
```

to:

```
#define howmany 10
int goal[howmany];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first `swaped` is not the same as `swapped`. It seems you hit a nasty *spelling* error, which if you set your compiler preferences to show warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) would have been readily apparent.

Following the spelling issue, another warning you would have found is `temp` was being used uninitialized. Which it turn would have led you to discover your bubblesort was `FUBAR`. (it also helps to place a `'\n'` at the end of your original/sorted list `printf` statements)

All of your loop limits printing the values must be `for (i = 0; i < howmany; i++)` **NOT** `for (i = 0; i <= howmany; i++)` (`<=` will cause you to read beyond the end of the array.)

Finally, you would have found from your error messages that `stdlib.h` was needed for `rand()`.

Take a look at the following, you can implement the bubblesort in the body of your code if you want, or simply call it as a function as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* rand() */

#define howmany 10

void bubblesort (int *a, size_t n);

int main() {


    int i/*,temp = 0,swapped*/; 
    // int howmany = 10;
    int goal[howmany];


    for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
        goal[i] = (rand() % 40)+1;
    }
    printf("orignal list\n");
    for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goal[i]);
    }

    bubblesort (goal, howmany);
//     while (1) {
//         swapped = 0;
//         for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
//             if (goal[i] > goal[i + 1]) {
//                 goal[i] = temp;
//                 goal[i] = goal[i + 1];
//                 goal[i + 1] = temp;
//                 swapped = 1;
//             }
// 
//         }
//         if (swapped == 0) {
//             break;
//         }
// 
//         printf("sorted list");
//         for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
//             printf("%d \n", goal[i]);
//         }
//     }
    printf("sorted list\n");
    for (i = 0;i < howmany;i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goal[i]);
    }
    // _getch();
    return 0;
}

void bubblesort (int *a, size_t n)
{
    size_t i, j;
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (n-1); j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                temp = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/vsnoconst
orignal list
24
7
18
36
34
16
27
13
10
22
3
sorted list
7
10
13
16
18
22
24
27
34
36
```

Comment: code fixed, so I deleted my prior comment, will delete this one later.

Comment: Why `(int)` cast in `bubblesort ()`?  Recommend `size_t i, j`